# Connecting via netcat and sending commands in bash script

Tags: bash, macos, tcp, telnet, netcat

I am trying to log into a device via netcat and send commands using a bash script. I would like to contain the username and password in the bash script as well as the commands I'd like to send. Ive tried the following;

```
#!/bin/bash

netcat 192.168.1.210 23 <<END #connect to device via telnet
pakedge #enter username
pakedgep #enter password
ps 0 #execute command
END
```

The connection just hangs at password and doesn't move forward. I am on a mac using GNU netcat 0.7.1. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn netcat 192.168.1.210 23
expect "name:"
send "pakedge\r"
expect "password:"
send "pakedgep\r"
expect ">"
send "ps 1\r"
interact
```